# Adobe Analytics tl call in onunload event not working

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

We are trying to define a page abandonment as someone who leaves before the DOM is ready.

I am trying to have an event triggered when someone unloads a page before the Dom is ready.  Adobe DTM is firing a HTML sequential tag at the top of the page setting the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="pageAbandon">

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
        s.events = 'event22';
        s.linkTrackEvents = 'event22';
        s.tl();
      }
    };

</script>
```

The event seems to be intermediately firing.  In testing I had the event fire on every page unload to see if this was a viable option.  In a two hour window, we only got 150 event counts with a couple thousand visits.  I am wondering if the s.tl server call is taking to long during the unload event and the data is not making it back to our analytics suite.  Is there a faster way or better implementation to get this kind of information?

**EDIT:**  It looks like the problem with not collecting data stems from the time it takes to make the server call back to Adobe.  I increased the delay on the s.tl() call and started getting data into Adobe Analytics.  You can do this by setting s.forcedLinkTrackingTimeout = newDelayTime.  The delay is in milliseconds and the default is 250ms.  I set it to 500ms and it seems to be working now.

**EDIT:** 2/2/2017  Changing the delay on the s.tl() call worked for two days before breaking again.  I haven't figured out why yet ... stay tuned.

Comment: "150 event counts with a couple thousand visits" - are you sure that more than 150 visits had the user unload the page before DOM ready? I doubt that a majority of visitors would meet this criteria, so 150/2000 doesn't sound unreasonable. That said, browsers don't guarantee that network requests will go through when initiated on unload, in order to preserve the fastest user experience. I've seen a number of times where an analytics call fired on form submit was canceled by the browser.